# Unexpected String Constant Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
{name:'Second section',fields:['Column_x0020_2', 'Column_x0020_3'],mouseOver:'This is the second section',sectionStyle:",clickFunction: ’secondSectionClick(this)’}],settings:{bgColor: '#8EB4E8',hoverColor: '#FFF68F',selectedColor: '#C6E2FF',formBgColor: '#C6E2FF'},clickFunctionShared: ’clickFunctionShared(this)’};
```

What is syntax error in this? I am trying to build accordian for sharepoint list. Please help

Comment: `sectionStyle` is missing a quote, messing up the entire object so it's just a big syntax error, which you would have seen had you formatted your code properly.

Comment: ... and some of the quotes are the wrong ones. See, e.g., the end of your object.

Comment: Still No luckI am pasting my code in JSfiddle. Please help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ewu12fbe/2/

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few syntax errors in that one little line. Here is my best guess of what you're actually trying to achieve.

```
{
    name: "Second section",
    fields: ["Column_x0020_2", "Column_x0020_3"],
    mouseOver: "This is the second section",
    sectionStyle: "",
    clickFunction: function () {
        secondSectionClick(this);
    },
    settings: {
        bgColor: "#8EB4E8",
        hoverColor: "#FFF68F",
        selectedColor: "#C6E2FF",
        formBgColor: "#C6E2FF"
    },
    clickFunctionShared: function () {
        clickFunctionShared(this);
    }
};
```